# Blender 3.0 Donut Tutorial Issue

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices

[image]

I'm trying to work my way through the 3.0 Donut Tutorial - I wasn't too far in (near the end of Part 4), when I ran into an issue that required me to go back and start over again from Part 3, from the point of duplicating half my mesh to make the icing, reapplying all the modifiers, and so forth.

However, I seem to have done something wrong where I now can't make the vertices appear on my icing in Edit mode - I can view it in Wireframe mode, I can make the vertices appear on the donut, but not the icing. As the screenshot hopefully shows, it's almost like the vertices are under the icing, or else outlining it.

Some other settings went weird in the restart, like the viewport overlay being turned off so I couldn't see the grid (since fixed), but I'm having trouble finding out what might have happened here. Can anyone help?

Comment: Ah, that isn't any bug. The vertices are INDEED under the icing, and that is because the *Offset* of your *Solidify* modifier is set to 1. 1 means the mesh will expand outwards, and -1 means it'll expand inwards. 0 signifies expansion equal expansion on both sides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't see the vertices because the solidify modifier is covering it. You can either :

- Turn on X-Ray mode with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> or the toggle button on the top right or bottom right.

[image]

- Enable cage edit in the modifier. Multiple modifiers have this option which allows you to edit the mesh as if the modifier is already applied.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yep, cage edit was what I needed to start seeing what I expected to see again. Thank you! Marked as answered.