# Missing parts of mesh

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices

I'm trying to create a donut. I selected some points and scaled them down but after it, some part of the mesh (icing) vanished. This isn't inside the donut(torus), it is just missing (maybe). Please help me to solve this and explain the actual problem and how to avoid it in the future?

blender file - [image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: probably the vertices you've selected are snapping onto the donut underneath, maybe select all the vertices and make them snap onto the donut? If it doesn't work please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: You might have hidden them. Try alt+h in Editmode to unhide vertices.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/249610/blender-3-0-donut-tutorial-issue?rq=1 ?

Comment: @moonboots I tried it but it isn't working. I attached the file in the question. Thank you for helping.

Comment: @BentleyCarpenter I tried unhiding it is not working too. I have attached the file in the question. thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

There is no more faces on this part, it's hard to tell how it happened, but now just fill the hole with some faces. First select these two edges:

[image]

Then right click > *LoopTools > Bridge* (enable the *LoopTools* addon) and choose 5 segments in the *Operator* box:

[image]

To make the vertices merge, press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*, in the Operator box choose a *Merge Distance* of 0.001:

[image]

Fill the last faces with some <kbd>F</kbd>:

[image]